# How do I collaborate and share presentations, pictures, etc in Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I would kindly like to know how I collaborate and share presentations, pictures, etc. in Ubuntu One. Please help me in the simplest way possible as I'm new to Ubuntu One.

Answer (score 1):

Their are two options for sharing using Ubuntu One. Their is a 'Share' and a 'Publish' option. Publish is for files and allows you to share that file with anyone via a public URL. 'Share' is for folders and can only be between Ubuntu One users. This is because the Share feature syncs the folder between the two users.

**Publish a File**

You can share files through a public URL by using the 'Publish' feature. If you are on Ubuntu right-click on a file synced with Ubuntu One and select Ubuntu One > Publish.
[image: Publish File - desktop]

Ubuntu One will generate a public URL that you can use to share that file. After it is published right-click on the file and select 'Copy Web Link' to copy the URL to your clipboard.
[image: Publish URL-desktop]

You can also Publish files using the web interface. Visit https://one.ubuntu.com/files and click 'More' next to the file you want to Publish. This will reveal the publishing options.
[image: Publish File - web]
Click 'Publish File' and you will then see a Public URL that you can use to share the file. 
[image: Publish URL-web]
You can quit publishing the file by clicking 'Stop Publishing'. Once a file is published its name will appear blue in the web interface for easy identification. if you are on Windows you will need to use the web interface to Publish files.

**Share a Folder**

Ubuntu One gives you the option to 'Share' folders with other Ubuntu One users. In Ubuntu if you right-click on a folder that is synced with Ubuntu One and select Ubuntu One > Share a dialog will pop up asking you for the email of the Ubuntu One user you wish to share the file with.
[image: Share Folder - desktop]

Use the email that they use with Ubuntu One. The person you are sharing with will receive an email telling them you wish to share a folder with them. You can select to give the people you share with Read only or Read/Write privileges.

You can also Share folders using the web interface. Click 'More' next to the folder you wish to Share. This will reveal the Share options. Click 'Share Folder' to Share the folder with another Ubuntu One user.
[image: Share Folder - web]
A dialog will pop up allowing you to enter the email of the Ubuntu One user you wish to Share with. You will also have the opportunity to select Read or Read/Write privileges for the people you are sharing with. That user will receive an email notifying them that you wish to Share a folder. Once a folder is shared its name will appear in blue in the web interface for easy identification. If you click More next to a folder that you are sharing you will see the email of the people you are sharing with as well as whether or not they have accepted your share or you are waiting on them to accept.
[image: Share Folder - status]
Click 'Stop Publishing' to quit sharing the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can login into your **Ubuntu One account on the web** (https://one.ubuntu.com/)
Then in the Files and folders list (Files tab), click on the right of a folder where the **link "More"** is diplayed. You will see two options: "Share folder", and "Stop syncing this folder".
The option that you need is **"Share folder"**. You click on this, and a popup window will appear with the options to share your folder with someone.
You can choose if the other person can update or only read your folder.
So, you can collaborate with others, sharing your folder.